# Questions about Message Access Profile (MAP) in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth

I can't get an answers to these questions:

1. Can a BT device send out SMS over Message Access Profile (MAP) in iPhone?
2. What about MMS? Can a BT accessory get notified about incoming MMS? Can it send out MMS?
3. Does MAP work for emails inbox as well, or for SMS only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

SMS,iMessage can be delivered using MAP Profile.

You can use push notifications for SMS and iMessage and can send these messages to BT devices using MAP Profile.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't ask about BLE.

Answer (score 1):

MAP uses OBEX protocol for Message transfer 
1. Not sure about iPhone, but MAP mandates for message transfer between devices
2. Notification is mandatory for both client and server in MAP(server being phone and BT Acc'y as a client). Phone needs to support SMS and MMS mandatory as per MAP Spec, so MMS notifications can be send to BT accessory .It depends on bt accessory to send MMS or not
3.MAP is for all message types- SMS , MMS and Email. EMail is not mandatory so depends on implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm looking for iPhone specific answers :)